# RK4 Order of Global Truncation Error Confusion

Tags: integration, runge-kutta-methods

I'm currently trying to integrate an equation using an RK4 integrator and I'm getting confused with regards to the global truncation error.

The problem consists of an integration from $t = 0$ seconds to $t = 258492$ seconds using a step-size of $2$ seconds. The question is: what would be the order of the error at the end of the integration?

I know that the global truncation error of the RK4 integration scheme is $O(h^4)$, but I'm confused as to what step-size $h$ I should use here to calculate the order of the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first get our definitions straight, then the confusion should be almost gone.

Given an Interval $I=[t_0, t_0+T]$ and the following separation 
$$t_0<t_1<…<t_N=t_0+T$$ 
the step-size is defined as $h_n:= t_n-t_{n-1}$.

A one-step method 
$$u_n = u_{n-1}+h_nF(t_n,h_n;u_{n-1},u_n)$$
is called consistent of order $p$ if for the truncation error 
$$τ_n=h_n^{-1}(u(t_n)-u(t_{n-1}))-F(t_{n-1},h_n;u(t_{n-1}),u(t_n))$$
it holds
$$\max_{t_n∈I}\|τ_n\|=\mathcal{O}(h^p),$$
for $h=\max_{1≤n≤N}h_n→0$.

If the method applied to an ODE is also stable, then it converges with order $p$. The applied method is stable, if the right hand side $f$ of the ODE $u'=f$ fulfils some Lipschitz-condition. 
Keep in mind, that there still might be some kind of step-size restriction.

The global truncation error $\|u(t_n) -u_n\|$ is just the accumulation of the (local) truncation error.

The important part is, that you consider $h→0$. If we are speaking about convergence, we mean convergence with respect to the step-size $h$ getting smaller.

Therefore, you can't tell if your RK method is of order $4$, if you only calculate the result for one step-size $h$.

Assuming convergence of your problem, try the following: 
Solve for $h_i=2^{-i}$, $i=0,1,2,...$ and calculate:
$$α_i = \frac{1}{\log(2)} \log\left(\left|\frac{a(h_i)-a(h_{i+1})}{a(h_{i+1}) - a(h_{i+2})}\right|\right)$$
with $a(h) = u(t_{N})$ for stepsize $h$.
You should see $α_i\approx 4$.
Do a check and solve with some Euler method or Crank Nicolson.

The formula above assumes, that there exists some convergence $a(h)-a = \mathcal{O}(h^α)$.

Comment: So the order of the method depends on the problem? I thought the RK4 method simply had accuracy $h^4$. Does this then also mean that I can say nothing about the order of the error using solely the start & end time and the step-size?

Comment: @arphelior You are correct, and I never said otherwise. A method is of order $p$ *for $h→0$*.  But it also depends on the ODE, if or if not your method converges to a solution. That is why there are two different definitions: Convergence = consistency + stability;  see also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation_error_(numerical_integration)#Relationship_between_local_and_global_truncation_errors).  And that is also why I wrote at the end `Assuming convergence of your problem`.

Comment: And yes, only computing the solution for on step-size you can't say anything about convergence.

Comment: Probably two mere typos: In $$\max_{t∈I}\|τ_n\|=\mathcal{O}(h^p)$$
we do not know what $$t∈I$$ means, and in $$h=\max_{1≤n≤N}→0$$ the argument of the maximum is missing. (Anyway, +1.)

Comment: Ah I see, thank you for clarifying that. So, if we assume that the method converges to a solution for a problem (and that there is therefore consistency & stability), how would one find the order of the global truncation error? For example in the problem stated above, would it then be $O(2^4)$, $O((2/258492)^4)$ or neither? (again assuming that the method converges for this problem).

Comment: @Did Thanks, edited according to your comment. It should be clear now.

Comment: Sorry, to be slightly more precise, I meant the global truncation error at the end of the integration (thus the accumulation of the local truncation error after the full integration)

Comment: @arphelior The Landau-notation is also a limit, so you can say for the global truncation error $e_h$ it holds $$e_h:=\|u(t_N)-u_N\| = \mathcal{O}(h^p),\text{ for } h→0.$$  That translates to: $e_h$ behaves like $h^p$ for $h→0$.  Saying $e_h$ behaves like $2^4$  or like $(2/258492)^4$ does not make sense, right?  // I would like to note that the interesting interpretation of "order" is: If you half (=$\frac{1}{2^1}$) the stepsize, you will see a reduction of $\frac{1}{2^p}$ in your error.

Comment: @P.Siehr Indeed, it does not make sense. However, I found a source claiming that to be the error. The source integrated an equation from $0$ to $2\pi$ using a stepsize of $2\pi/100$ and mentioned that the order of the global truncation error would therefore be $(2\pi/100)^4$ (hence confusing me).

With regards to the definition of "order", thanks a lot for clarifying that. Am I correct in concluding then that to be able to calculate the order of the global truncation error using a certain step-size, the global truncation error at a different step-size should be known?

Comment: @arphelior Well if you know the global truncation error for the  step-size $\tilde{h}$, you can estimate the global truncation error for the step-size $\hat{h}$, if you know how $\tilde{h}$ and $\hat{h}$ are connected. E.g. $\tilde{h}= \hat{h}/2$.   But usually you don't even know the global truncation error for $\tilde{h}$ in the first place.

Comment: Excellent, thank you _very_ much for your thorough explanation. I've marked your response as the answer to my question.

Comment: $$\max_{t∈I}\|τ_n\|\qquad >\qquad\max_{1≤n≤N}\|τ_n\|\ ?$$

Comment: @Did Thanks, it should have been $\max_{t_n∈I}$

Comment: Hmmm... Sorry but the notation $$\max_{t_n\in I}\|\tau_n\|$$ seems absurd since, once some subdivision $(t_n)$ is fixed, $(\tau_n)$ is just a real-valued  sequence.